# Lucene - lazy load fields from documents

Tags: lucene, load, field, document, lazy-evaluation

Someone has an idea, how to load fields lazy by lucene searcher?
I don't get it...

My Lucene-Indexs' Documents contains fields like this:

- UF1: Unstored Field 1
- UF2: Unstored Field 2
- ...: Some other unstored Fields
- SF1 - Stored Field 1
- SF2 - Stored Field 2 -> But this one has very very much text

So now I'm searching on the index. When I get very much result docs, it seems, that all content in SF2 is beeing loaded by lucene, so RAM goes up very very fast.
But, the only field I need to get by this search is SF1. SF2 will never be used by this search.

Is it possible to exclude that special Field "SF2" from beeing loaded into the resulting Documents.

```java
// Some initializing and query preparing...
final IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(this.getReader());
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, maxResults);
ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = hits.scoreDocs;
for (final ScoreDoc score : scoreDocs) {
    final Document document = searcher.doc(score.doc);
    final String value = document.get("SF1"); // <-- This is the only needed field of result doc
    // collecting value ...
}
```

edit: Lucene 4.1 Java-API

Answer (score 2):

Both `IndexReader` and `IndexSearcher` have method `.document(int docID, Set<String> fieldsToLoad)` where you can specify which fields do you want to load.

Simply use that and exclude what is not necessary.

Comment: Hi mindas, thanks for your quick response! I'll try that and report the results. For now i can say, that the memory consumption looks as high as it was before (without the Set of Field(s)). Do you know, if lucene internally maybe loads all fields here: `TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, maxResults);`

Comment: `TopDocs`, if I remember correctly, only contains array with references to documents in the index and nothing else.

Comment: Back again! Just compared some queries with fieldsToLoad and without. Connected with jconsole to my program there is quietly no difference between them in RAM consumption. I experimented with `IndexSearcher.search` and `IndexSearcher.searchAfter` to load results step by step. But that is dropping down speed drastically.

Comment: So maybe your RAM problem isn't really coming from the fact that SF2 field is loaded but because of other reasons?